# How to increase Oil Well Generation in Build Craft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-tekkit

Since oil is hard to get and you need it to get fuel, how do I make oil wells generate more often?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In order to increase Oil Well generation, you need to got the `config` file, goto `buildcraft`, then goto `main.cfg`, open it using notepad or something. scroll down to where it says `D:oilWellGenerationRate=1.0`, then just change the number to a number < 100. You MUST include the `.0`.

Comment: be careful with this. Places that are already abundant in oil (like  deserts) will pretty much become an.. oil biome.

Answer (score -1):

You can go to the config file under AppData>.minecraft>config>buildcraft and set it to a number that is lower than 100. Setting it to a number above 10 usually means the world won't generate.

Comment: This does not add anything new.